# why train score is less than validation score?

Tags: machine-learning

what are probable situation that cause train score become lower than validation score? 
I trained both linear regression and neural network but in both validation score is higher than train score?

Answer (score 0):

It means your model is a **weak learner**.
You may need to use power models with many more parameters.
Other thing you created some bad parameter assumption for your model, especially in case of non parametric models.